# Avoid SignalR connection drop when using it inside WPA for notification

Tags: signalr, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm implementing notification with signalr and pwa in mobile device. Everything works well while browser is open in mobile device. Also in server side I'm using asp.net mvc + Microsoft signalr. I can keep connection alive inside Browser with no problem (reconnect...) , but in PWA that's another story , since I can't use jQuery inside service worker (due to its nature there is no html DOM accessible).

Is there any way that I can keep signalr alive with pwa? like when browser gets closed or goes inactive for a while? also I'm trying to avoid GCM and FCM.(corporation policy)